# Production expresion for Taylor series expansión.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, products

i need help, I am doing the Taylor series development around the origin of:

$\sqrt{z+i}$, i have considerated $\sqrt{z+i}=\sqrt{i} \sqrt{1+\frac{z}{i}}$ and make the variable change $x= \frac{z}{i}$ and doing the development in Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$

But i have found that the expression of the nth derivate is:

$(\frac{1}{2}-0) (\frac{1}{2}-1) (\frac{1}{2}-2)... (\frac{1}{2}-(n-1))$

You know how i can get an expression for that since? i need to calculate the radius convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the binomial theorem
$$\sqrt{z+i}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty i^{\frac{1}{2}-n} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} z^n$$

Comment: Thank you, very much, but how i could i do to get the radius of convergence through thet expression?

Comment: Compute $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ and compute its limit. It is simple.